# Почему не выводится лучший результат сразу после проигрыша, а только через одну игру и как это исправить?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я сейчас делаю бесконечный спейс шутер и возникла проблема, заключающаяся в том, что выводит лучший результат не сразу в следующей игре после проигрыша, а только через одну игру.
Не знаю в чем заключается ошибка. Прошу подсказать где нужно исправить код, чтобы можно было выводить результат сразу после поражения если конечно был достигнут лучший результат.

```
public static PlayerController instance;
Vector2 PositionPlayer;
float speed = 5f;
float limitX = 8.2f;
public GameObject BulletPrefub;
Transform ejectPosition;
public bool CanShoot = true;
Text txtScore;

Wave waveScript;
bool detect = true;
public GameObject AlienBullet;
bool alienCanShoot = true;
int layerDefault;
public float AlienShootRate = 3f;


public Text bestScore;

private int score = 0;
private int best = 0;
public int Score
{
    get
    {
        return score;
    }

    set
    {
        score = value;
        txtScore.text = "Score: " + score;
        bestScore.text = "Best: " + best;
    }
}

void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}

void Start()
{
    PositionPlayer = transform.position;
    ejectPosition = transform.Find("Eject");
    txtScore = GameObject.Find("TxtScore").GetComponent<Text>();

    best = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("best", 0);

    txtScore.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
    bestScore.text = "Best: " + best.ToString();

    waveScript = GameObject.Find("Wave").GetComponent<Wave>();
    layerDefault = LayerMask.GetMask("Default");
}


void Update()
{
    if(best < score)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("best", score);
    }
    
    MovePlayer();
    PLayerShoot();
    AlienShoot();
}

void MovePlayer()
{
    if(CanShoot)
    {
        PositionPlayer.x += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        PositionPlayer.x = Mathf.Clamp(PositionPlayer.x, -limitX, limitX);
        transform.position = PositionPlayer;
    }
}

void PLayerShoot()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && CanShoot)
    {
        Instantiate(BulletPrefub, ejectPosition.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.tag == "Alien" & detect || collision.tag == "BulletAlien")
    {
        detect = false;
        StartCoroutine(AlienKillPlayer());
        print("Player dead");
    }
}

IEnumerator AlienKillPlayer()
{
    waveScript.StopWave();
    PlayerExplosion();
    GameObject.Find("Health").GetComponent<Lives>().LoseSlot();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
    detect = true;
    waveScript.RestartWave(1f);
}

void PlayerExplosion()
{
    GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("explosion");
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    CanShoot = false;
}

public void InitPlayer()
{
    GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("normal");
    CanShoot = true;
}

void AlienShoot()
{
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.up * 5);

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up, Mathf.Infinity, layerDefault);

    if(hit.collider!=null)
    {
        if(hit.collider.CompareTag("Alien") && alienCanShoot)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Pause());
            GameObject Go = Instantiate(AlienBullet, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(Go, 10f);
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator Pause()
{
    alienCanShoot = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(AlienShootRate);
    alienCanShoot = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мало работал с `PlayerPrefs`, но:

1. после занесения данных нужно выполнить `PlayerPrefs.Save()`
2. если не перезагружается сцена, то не выполнится код в `Start`

```
   best = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("best", 0);

   bestScore.text = "Best: " + best.ToString();
```

Comment: не работает так, все как было так и осталось

Comment: для начала следующей игры сцена не перезагружается?